# Probability that minimum of set of random variables is specific element

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Say I have a set of $n$ random variables, $\lbrace X_1, ..., X_n \rbrace$, each with distribution $f_{X_i}(x \mid \theta_i)$. What is $\mathbb{P}\left[\min(X_1, ..., X_n) = X_j\right]$?

I assume this will require some convolution of probabilities as this is how I would do it for $n=1, 2, 3$ but I can't see how to generalise for arbitrary $n$.

Comment: There is nothing you can do unless you assume something between the $X_i.$ (Are they independent?)

Comment: Is it just a special case that it works for $n=2$ then? $\mathbb{P}[\min(X_1, X_2) = X_1] = \mathbb{P}[X_1 < X_2] = \int_{X_2} \mathbb{P}[X_1 < x_2 \mid X_2 = x_2]\mathbb{P}[X_2 = x_2]dx_2$

Comment: @Sockey the same formula generalizes to $n>2$ but it might not be that helpful: $\mathbb{P}[\min(X_1,...,X_n) = X_j] = \mathbb{P}[X_i \le X_j \forall i] = \int_{X_j} \mathbb{P}[X_1 \le x_j \cap ... \cap X_n \le x_j \mid X_j = x_j]\mathbb{P}[X_j = x_j]dx_j$